# How do I set docker date and ensure that it does NOT sync with my system time?

Tags: docker, time

I am attempting to set the docker date in one of my containers to be in the past so that I can run time-dependent tests.
I run this command:

`docker exec -it mycontainername date -s "2018-04-19 10:00:00"`

which correctly outputs `Thu Apr 19 10:00:00 UTC 2018`, indicating the date was set properly.

However, **within a couple of minutes** after **not doing anything**, running

`docker exec -it mycontainername date`

yields

`Fri Sep  7 14:45:56 UTC 2018` (the current time)

It would appear that docker is periodically syncing this container's time with my system time (I'm on a Mac). What can I do to keep it stuck on the time I set?

Answer (score 0):

Date is not a namespaced property in a container, there is a single OS clock that applies to the host and every container being run. Without configuring the container with additional capabilities, you will be unable to change the date on the host. And if you do give the container the ability to change the date on the host, other processes on the host, like an ntp daemon, may reset the time back.